# Problem CORS Policy in this case while it works for other resources

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I build my API with Laravel. In front-end, I use Vuejs with Nuxtjs.

The CORS policy policy package is installed and works with all my other resources.

For one of my features, it does not work. The following error appears and I do not understand why:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myapp.test/api/bilan/storestatus' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
11:22:48.855 

POST http://myapp.test/api/bilan/storestatus net::ERR_FAILED
```

I did this:

```
<el-switch v-model="status.status" @change="storeStatus">
</el-switch>
```

```
data() {
  status: { status: 0 }
}
```

```
async storeStatus() {
        try {
            await axios.post('bilan/storestatus', this.status)
                .then( () => {
                    this.$message({
                        message: this.$t('status.updated'),
                        type: 'success'
                    })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
},
```

Can you explain to me why I am getting this error?

Especially that everything works fine on the rest of my application.

Comment: if you are absolutely certain that the CORS policies are correct and the `localhost` origin should be allowed to access `myapp.test/api/bilan/storestatus` then check the actual response. Sometimes the successful responses do provide the correct CORS headers but if there is an error the error header does not provide any CORS headers so the browser fails the request due to CORS reasons while in reality the request failed due to other reasons (in addition to CORS)

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for your response. For this query, I don't see any CORS in the header. How to see where the problem comes from? I advance to the blind

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan route:cache`

You can try these codes, if the problem occurred when you developing

Comment: There's 2 requests you should be getting, one is `OPTIONS` and the other one is the `POST`. If the first request succeeds then check the status code and content of the 2nd request if it's an error then the problem is probably not CORS but an actual code bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your request have an internal error? An issue with the CORS policy package is Laravels default error handler will create new response headers. If the request is ran through the error handler it will remove the CORS headers. So if you have an internal error on your request, you won't get a 500 error, you'll get a CORS error due to the response headers being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable CORS in the server also. then add 
`axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';`

Or it was a problem in the server not accepting options requests. You will more details about CORS in https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/